# Загрузка товаров в Битрикс через файловую выгрузку из 1С

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с, cms

Возможно ли загрузить товары из 1С в Битрикс не обменом (через 1c_exchange.php), а посредством импорта файла (архив .rar), который формирует сам 1С? Если да, то как правильно такое делать (какими средствами)?
Структура архива, который формируется с 1С следующая: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал подсовывать этот xml файл в модуль импорта - не читается.
Буду благодарен за любые подсказки/мысли.

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает стандартный обмен?

Comment: @rusgeli он не работает по непонятным причинам пока что. Поэтому было решено попробовать залить выгруженный из 1С архив. Но вот каким образом это сделать - тоже пока непонятно.

Comment: А если с архивом тоже не будет работать, то что дальше? Может надо все таки понять почему не работает первый вариант?

Comment: @u_mulder вот есть мысль, что архив из 1С некорректный формируется, поэтому битрикс его не кушает корректно. Но в то же время, чтобы в этом убедиться, надо на 100% быть уверенным, что я правильно этот архив пытаюсь скормить. Поэтому скрин и приложил со структурой.